# pytelegrambotapi check bot permissions in groups

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I am trying to fix an error where the bot tries to send a message to a chat group but doesn't have administration permissions.

I need an `if` statement like the one below before sending the message to the chat group, however this code is not working:

```
if bot.get_chat(Message.chat.id).permissions.can_send_messages:
    bot.reply_to(NewMessage, response, parse_mode="HTML")
```

Do you know what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *[get_chat_member](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.get_chat_member)* method to get information about a member of a chat. Returns a ChatMember object on success.

**PARAMETERS:**

**chat_id** (int or str) – Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target supergroup (in the format @supergroupusername)

**user_id** (int) – Unique identifier of the target user.

Returns [ChatMember](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ChatMember) object.

**EXAMPLE**

```
bot_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, bot.id)

if bot_member.can_send_messages:
    bot.reply_to(NewMessage, response, parse_mode="HTML")
```